# Extract only letter characters from a string in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Here is the example string:

"DOGE495.96"

I would like to use AppleScript to extract only "DOGE"

How would I go accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this method to work without having to write the entire alphabet:

```applescript
set theString to "DOGE495.96"
set newString to ""

repeat with i from 1 to count of characters in theString
    if id of character i of theString > 64 and id of character i of theString < 122 then set newString to newString & character i of theString
end repeat

return newString
```

Output:

```
"DOGE"
```

This, however, doesn't work with diacriticals. For those, you would have to do something like this:

```applescript
set theString to "Ÿėś āńd Ñó"
set newString to ""

repeat with i from 1 to count of characters in theString
    ignoring diacriticals and case
        if "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" contains character i of theString then set newString to newString & character i of theString
    end ignoring
end repeat

return newString
```

Outputs:

```
"ŸėśāńdÑó"
```

<sup>More advanced diacriticals like ß are not considered, since they count as separate characters.</sup>

Both methods do not include whitespace, which for the lower one can easily be added, and for the upper one, the `if`-statement needs to be modified like this:

```applescript
if (id of character i of theString > 64 and id of character i of theString < 122) or character i of theString = space then set newString to newString & character i of theString
```

Comment: Thank for for this. This worked.

Comment: @WaylandChin Be aware that the upper would have to be modified because it would currently include some special punctuation like `[]\^_`

Answer (score 2):

If your source strings always contain only letters, numbers, and ".", then one very quick and simple solution is using text item delimiters.

```
set sourceString to "DOGE495.96"

set ATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "."}
set tempString to text items of sourceString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID

set resultString to tempString as text
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess AppleScript has not built in method for extracting text only, so we have to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab just the letters with a single shell script using `tr`:

```
set sString to "DOGE495.96"

set lString to do shell script "echo " & sString & " | tr -cd '[[:alpha:]]'"
```

The -c has it use the complement (or everything but) the last item, in this case 'alpha' class characters. The -d causes deletion of everything that matches, in this case, everything that isn't a letter.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have to read more about tr.